# Command line for "x64 checked build environment"

Tags: sdk, windows-8.1, wdk

I have installed WDK and SDK on my Pc.. I can see them on my system.. But I am not able to get "x64 checked build environment command prompt"..My OS is windows 8.1 .. If anyone has a solution to the problem please do let me know

Comment: Maybe you ought to pay attention to the "not available" annotation in [this web page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554644%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  It isn't clear what OS you want to target, the usual problem with very short questions about very large topics.

Comment: OS is Windows 8.1. I want to build virtual box 4.3. To do that I want to run a few commands on "x64 checked build environment command prompt". But I am not able to locate it inside WDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you open a VS developer prompt, you should have access to MSBUILD and from there, you need to use MSBuild command line parameters to build for x64 chk project. These variables would be /p:platform=x64 and /p:configuration=Win7 Debug. WDK will pick the right cross arch compiler and build for the respective configuration.